# How can I make my router send all web traffic to a specific proxy?

Tags: proxy, wireless-router, routing

I'm trying to create a WiFi hotspot using an ASUS Wireless Router RT-N10+. The main internet connection does not use DHCP. It requires a static IP configuration and a proxy to use the web.

I set the IP and subnet in the ASUS router's control panel, but there is no setting for proxy. After connecting a laptop to the WiFi, I need to manually set the proxy in my own laptop to use the web.

So all users will be needed to set this proxy in their own devices. Which is a troublesome experience. This will be a free WiFi hotspot on a university campus for the students, who will use it from mobile phones also.

So I don't want the clients of the WiFi network to need to set a proxy. Is there any way to set the proxy within the router?

If the built-in firmware can not satisfy the need, Can you suggest any third party firmware that will have the proxy setting inside the router?

Is it possible to implement the proxy setting using routing tables?

Answer (score 1):

The ASUS Wireless Router RT-N10+ is able to pass through VPN traffic but doesn't have an option to tunnel all traffic through a proxy.

It isn't possible to do this with routing. Routing sends all the traffic to the server, I'm assuming you are talking about sending HTTP-only traffic to a HTTP-proxyserver.

You could install the custom DD-WRT firmware, [other people](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=70505&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0) succeeded with the same router. Warning: you may overwrite your current firmware and ruin your router.

If you managed to install this you can then configure a [transparant web proxy](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy).

You may encounter more problems with DNS traffic, make sure your router runs a DNS server and use that one on the client PCs.